# array variable index in that rare SimpleXML functions

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

I have a label on a form select and I get that value with $ _POST like this:

```
$gallery = array($_POST['gallery']);
```

and that value will put it here:

```
$image = $sitemap->gallery[$gallery]->addChild('image');
```

the problem is giving me error is as follows:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function addChild() on a non-object in
```

I do not understand is that if I put a value directly asin me do it like so:

```
$gallery = 0;
$Image = $sitemap->gallery[$gallery]->addChild('image');
```

I do well, what happens is that I want the user to choose,
Kind of strange as it may fix.

Comment: I have a label on a form select and I get that value with

Comment: $ gallery = array ($ _POST ['gallery']);
and what do I need to put the index to function simplexml

Comment: Please post your original code. Your existing code has tons of `syntax` errors cuz of space between `$` and variable names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understanding Arrays:

```
$gallery = array($_POST['gallery']);
echo "Gallery Array: <pre>".print_r($gallery,true)."</pre><br />";
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'value in array'
)
```

How to get the value out of an array:

```
echo "Get Array Value: ".$gallery[0]."<br />"; // You should be displaying the array index 0
```

Adding a custom index

```
$gallery = array('gallery' => $_POST['gallery']);
echo "Gallery Array: <pre>".print_r($gallery,true)."</pre><br />";
```

Output:
Array

```
(
    [gallery] => 'value in array'
)
```

Getting the value from the customer index array

```
echo "Get Array Value: ".$gallery['gallery']."<br />"; // You should be displaying the array index gallery
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
$gallery = $_POST['gallery'];
```

instead of this:

```
$gallery = array($_POST['gallery']);
```

You passing an array that you did not index properly

Or you can try it this way:

```
$gallery = array('gallery' => $_POST ['gallery']);
```

or

```
$image = $sitemap->gallery[$gallery[0]]->addChild('image');
```

either way should fix the problem

Comment: I do not think so, but I've fixed it with this simple function $id=intval($_POST['gallery']);

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much, but I tested this and is giving me the same error

```
  $gallery=array('gallery'=>$_POST['galeria']);
$image = $sitemap->gallery[$gallery]->addChild('image');
```

I do not understand the select form that I have is as follows:

```
<select id="textfield" name="galeria">
        <option id="textfield" value="">Escoger de la Lista</option>
        <?php
    $source = 'content.xml';
    // load as string
    $xmlstr = file_get_contents($source);
    $sitemap = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
    // load as file
    $sitemap = new SimpleXMLElement($source,null,true);
    //$bar_count = $sitemap->gallery->count();
    //for($i=0;$i<$bar_count;$i++){
    $contador="0";
    foreach($sitemap->gallery as $content) {
    $atributo = $content->attributes();
    echo "<option id='textfield' value='".$contador."'>".$atributo['Name']. "</option>";
    //}
    $contador++; 
    } 
    ?>
      </select>
```

anyway I've tried has done an echo and I get the result, do not really understand

Comment: this line: '$image = $sitemap->gallery[$gallery]->addChild('image');' Should be: '$image = '$sitemap->gallery[$gallery['gallery']->addChild('image');'

Comment: $sitemap->gallery[$gallery['gallery']->addChild('image');

Comment: You should edit your question and not post an answer unless you have answered your own question

Comment: $id=intval($_POST['gallery']);

Comment: I do not think so, but I've fixed it with this simple function   $id=intval($_POST['gallery']);

Comment: yes so instead of passing an array you are now casting that value to an integer $id=intval($_POST['gallery']);